# Javascript function with prototype within parent function prototype

Tags: javascript, function, object, prototype

Is this even possible?

```
function foo() {
    // do stuff
}
foo.prototype = {
    // stuff...
    bar: function() {
        // do some things with this, where this refers to foo
    },
    bar.prototype: {
        // set some definitions for bar to work with.
        // Where does "this" go and what does it refer to?
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, and I got some fundamental issue. I wasn't sure where to go so I asked here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You'd need to use

```
function bar() {...}
bar.prototype = {...};
function foo() {...}
foo.prototype.bar = bar;
```

Although this won't work. There is no reason to put the `bar` constructor on `foo`s prototype, because when instantiating bar objects by using `new ((new foo()).bar)()`, there will be no reference to the foo instance. You could equally use `new foo.prototype.bar()`.

Comment: that's made it a little clearer. I think I was approaching this the wrong way.