# Prototyping with Javascript Constructors

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, prototype

**Consider the Following Example**

```
var Foo = function(){
    this.identity = 'Foo';
};
Foo.prototype.bar = function(){
    this.identity = 'bar';
};
var fooInstance = new Foo(),
    bar = new fooInstance.bar();
```

**Question**

Within `bar`, how may I obtain the `fooInstance` variable? Is there a way for a child of `Foo` to recognize its parent as `fooInstance`? For example, how could I create a function in `bar` that would return `fooInstance`. A slight caveat is that bar must by created using the `prototype` command and cannot simply be nested in `Foo` to access any `Foo` instances that way.

**My Ideas and Why They Don't Work**

It would be possible to rewrite the functions like so

```
var Foo = function(){
    this.identity = 'Foo';
};
Foo.prototype.createBar = function(){
    var parent = this;
    function bar(){
        this.parent = parent;
        this.identity = 'bar';
    };
    return new bar();
};
var fooInstance = new Foo(),
    bar = fooInstance.createBar();
```

Yet for the purposes of creating easily readable code i would rather not use this approach if not needed.

**Further Clarification**

Let me put the question in context. I am prototyping on CanvasRenderingContext2D so that all contexts for the canvas element will contain my new method. Lets call that method foo and assume context is a created canvas context. How create a variable like so "new context.foo()" such that the foo function can use the context variable?

Comment: What is `fooInstance`? What are "children" and "parents" of `Foo`? What is that `bar` method you're calling but not defining? What do you mean by "prototype command"?

Comment: Btw, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object/13418980#13418980) might help you to understand the differences between variable and properties.

Comment: Let me put the question in context. I am prototyping on CanvasRenderingContext2D so that all contexts for the canvas element will contain my new method. Lets call that method foo and assume context is a created canvas context. How create a variable like so "new context.foo()" such that the foo function can use the context variable?

Comment: OK, I see your problem now. Just searching for a dupe, if I can't find it I'll answer your question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prototype for private sub-methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982562/prototype-for-private-sub-methods), maybe see also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11146884/1048572)

Comment: Hmm I may be missing something, but I'm unsure how that question helps. Essentially the question is how does a sub-method obtain it's parent dynamically.

Comment: I have, thank you, i left a comment for you

Comment: @HunterLarco: No, it really is the same situation (only that you cannot modify the parent constructor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how could I create a function in bar that would return fooInstance

If that function is called as a constructor (with `new`), you can't really do it. The [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), the only reference to the "parent" (the object on which you called the method) is set to the new instance in a constructor invocation. You can get the reference only with a closure, for example by creating the constructor in the parent's constructor function (which doesn't work for you) or by returning the constructor from a closure on the prototype (which you nearly got in the second example):

```
Foo.prototype.getBarCoonstructor = function() {
    var parentFoo = this;
    return function Bar() {
        // constructor things
        // using "parentFoo" reference
    };
};
// Usage:
var bar = new (foo.getBarConstructor()) (); // ugly.
```

Instead of creating new constructors for every call of `getBarConstructor`, you better should put it outside of the method and put `parentFoo` as an argument to it. Your idea was already quite good.

```
function Bar(parent) {
    // constructor things, referring "parent"
}
Bar.prototype.… = …;

Foo.prototype.createBar = function() {
    return new Bar(this); // passing the Foo instance
};
```

(@plalx has the same solution, but wrapped in a module closure)

Comment: Thank you, i guess the problem is that "this" is the only upward relationship between functions and that using a constructor effectively removes it. This is one of those moments where javascript frustrates me.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to reference the `fooInstance` object from the `bar` object, you could use dependency injection like this:

```
Foo.prototype.bar = function(fooInstance) {
    this.identity = 'bar';
    this.fooInstance = fooInstance;
};

var fooInstance = new Foo(),
    bar = new foo.bar(fooInstance);
```

You could simplify the creation process by implementing a factory function on `Foo`.

```
Foo.prototype.createBar = (function() {
    function Bar(parent){
        this.parent = parent;
        this.identity = 'bar';
    };

    return function () {
        return new Bar(this);
    };
})();

var fooInstance = new Foo(),
    bar = fooInstance.createBar();
```

Comment: This is precisely my idea as well, but I am designing an API and find this cumbersome to use as a user. However while the factory method eliminates the annoying need to pass arguments, within my program it logically makes more sense to use the new prefix and i would rather keep things logical for the users. Is it possible for a sub-method to get the original object dynamically? Normally bindings and the use of this could accomplish just that, but because of the nature of a constructor that doesn't apply here... Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

`Foo.prototype.bar` is simply a function on the prototype Object of Foo. There is no way for that function to know of its 'parent' unless you explicitly define it in its scope chain.

I.e. if you would do

```
var Foo = function(){
    this.identity = 'Foo';
};
var fooInstance = new Foo();

Foo.prototype.bar = function(){
    console.log(fooInstance); // retrieve from scope
    this.identity = 'bar';
};
bar = new foo.bar();
```

that would work.

Comment: Yes, but once i created more than one fooInstance that method would break. The code needs to be dynamic. Each fooInstance is unique and each bar instance must be able to obtain it's unique parent.